# About Tegmark's mathematical universe

Tags: philosophy, cellular-automata

I'm not sure anyone else than Tegmark himself can answer this, but why not give it a try.

1. Would Tegmark consider a cellular automata a mathematical structure?
2. If nature is mathematical, isn't it also possible that it is a cellular automata? The behaviour of a CA can't be predicted without going through its individual steps. Wouldn't that mean that even *if* nature is mathematical, it would still be unpredictable?

Comment: Who is Tegmark ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Tegmark

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, and wether you have watched this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgSZA3NPpBs . There's a possibility that the universe had an initial condition at the beginning at that it is run by a cellular automaton. But nobody knows. I can mention a few people who had the same ideas as Tegmark or similar to them: Ed Fredkin, Stephen Wolfram and perhaps James Gates. And some people in the past: Von Neumann, Konrad Zuse and perhaps Richard Hamming. I might have forgotten someone. But there are a good chunk of literature out there..

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Thanks, I'll have a look!